# Can't edit or delete CSS file. (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to the whole ASP.NET MVC business, and I'm having the weirdest problem. I've been working on a project (MVC3, Razor engine) for the past few days, and yesterday I backed up my project by duplicating its folder. I opened the duplicated project and started working, but I noticed something weird. none of the changes I was making in a CSS file appeared anywhere. I tried changing all sorts of things in it, deleting its content and **even deleting the whole file!** nothing works. no change. After deleting the whole CSS file from my project, I tried making some changes in the .cshtml file and it does change when I debug the project.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: How were you requesting the duplicate folder? For example, if you were requesting localhost, and your IIS is mapped to your original project, then any changes you made to the duplicate would not be reflected unless you debugged specifically through the VS debugger with Cassini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser probably cached the CSS file. `Ctrl+F5` should do the trick in most browsers, to reload the css too and make changes visible.

Comment: LOL! I feel so dumb. thank you all. but I don't understand, why in other times changes were immediately visible and this time weren't?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as a caching issue to me.

http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Answer (score 0):

Are the files read only in the copy?